# Drupal Content Image URI

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm trying to theme a view in Drupal 7. I have the view theme set-up and it is working fine. The issue that I have is that I can't see a way to override the `$content` variable passed into the `render()` function.

Is there a pre/process hook that I should be using or should it be done in a `.tpl` file using the `$node` variable?

Currently I'm looking at the `$node` variable but the image attached to the content has a url of `public://field/image/imagefield_JmDqqm.jpg` and I've not been able to find a function (so far) that will parse that url into the correct url to view the image on the page.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [file_create_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function is what you're after